# In mysql query while cast decimal value it show different values

Tags: mysql

My Query is as follows

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders 
 WHERE ODR_ID ='3573' 
   AND CAST(WIDTH AS DECIMAL) = CAST('1.500' AS DECIMAL) 
   AND CAST(BREADTH AS DECIMAL) = CAST('0.500' AS DECIMAL) 
 ORDER 
    BY ID DESC
```

but result is as follows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your cast is appled  to tew filter  (where condition)  not to the output  (select clause)

so try

```
SELECT CAST(WIDTH AS DECIMAL) W, CAST(BREADTH AS DECIMAL) B
  FROM orders 
 WHERE ODR_ID ='3573' 
   AND CAST(WIDTH AS DECIMAL) = CAST('1.500' AS DECIMAL) 
   AND CAST(BREADTH AS DECIMAL) = CAST('0.500' AS DECIMAL) 
 ORDER 
    BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [DECIMAL Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html):

> The declaration syntax for a `DECIMAL` column is `DECIMAL(M,D)`. The
> ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:
>
> - `M` is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
> - `D` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a  range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than `M`.
>
> If `D` is omitted, the default is 0. If `M` is omitted, the default is
> 10.

That means that `DECIMAL` is the same as `DECIMAL(10)` or `DECIMAL(10,0)`. Which is a 10-digits integer. Therefor `CAST('1.500' AS DECIMAL)` will round *1.5* to *2*, which explains your result.

So use the type that corresponds to your data. E.g. `DECIMAL(10,3)` (numbers betwen -9999999.999 and +9999999.999).

Also consider to store the data as what it is. In your case DECIMAL(M,D) instead of string. Then you will not need to cast anything.